# rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:81"

I have the above error after I did

> curl localhost:81/opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42/

shouldn't I be getting whatever is inside the index.php file? My php controllers are in /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42/. I have Apache2 listening in 80 as the reverse proxy server serving php endpoints to nginx. Index.php is just

> php echo "Hello";

File1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location  /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42 {
      try_files $uri $uri$is_args$args;
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
  }
}
```

Fil2: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myPage.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorVH.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName 54.172.180.152
    DocumentRoot /var/www/userExperience
    ProxyPass /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42 http://localhost:81
    ProxyPassReverse /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42 http://localhost:81

</VirtualHost>
```

I think the error is in the way how I'm calling:

> try_files $uri $uri$is_args$args;

in nginx.conf. I modified the line to: "try_files $uri$is_args$args =404;" and after I curled it. I started getting

> 404 Not Found

If anyone knows where is my error, I'd appreciate the help

Comment: You state that "My php controllers are in /opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42/", are there more than one PHP file or only `index.php`? What URL is used to access the other PHP files?

Comment: @RichardSmith there are multiple controllers inside ro42 besides a index.php file. Regarding the url access is publicipv4:81/opt/soa/adminControl/v1/ro42